# Printing Stream to Local Printer using Queue

Tags: c#, printing

my goal is to print any MemoryStream on local printer:

```
public void PrintStream(MemoryStream ms) {
  byte[] bytes = new byte[ms.Length];
  ms.Read(bytes, 0, (int)ms.Length);

  LocalPrintServer ps = new LocalPrintServer();
  PrintQueue printQueue = new PrintQueue(ps, "ZDesigner GC420t (EPL)");

  using (var job = printQueue.AddJob())
    using (var stream = job.JobStream)
      stream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
}
```

Of course the printer is working fine and it isn't the default printer. 
**The problem is that it prints nothing.**

If I change the target 'printer' this way:

```
PrintQueue printQueue = LocalPrintServer.GetDefaultPrintQueue();
```

It prints all right on the default printer.

If I ask the list of print queues this way, I'm going to get the Zebra:

```
LocalPrintServer server = new LocalPrintServer();
PrintQueueCollection queueCollection = server.GetPrintQueues(new[] { EnumeratedPrintQueueTypes.Local });
foreach (PrintQueue pq in queueCollection)
  Debug.WriteLine(pq.Name);
```

Any ideas are welcome.

Comment: an easier way to do would be save your stream into temp file and then print. Is this an option for you?

Comment: There are a lot of ways to lose with System.Printing.  The generic approach is covered by [this KB article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/322091).